# Have I utilized pointers properly in the updateDate function?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

I am working with a program that updates an inputted date and updates it. Taking into account days in the month and whether it's a leap year etc.

I'm attempting an exercise in the pointers chapter of 'Programming in C':

"Given the definition of a `date` structure as defined in this chapter, write a function called `dateUpdate()` that takes a pointer to a `date` structure as its argument and that updates the structure to the following day(see Program 8.4)."

Can you please tell me if I have done what was asked?

This is the original code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct date
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};


struct date dateUpdate (struct date today);
int numberOfDays (struct date d);
bool isLeapYear(struct date d);

int main (void)
{
    struct date thisDay, nextDay;

    printf("Enter today's date (mm dd yyyy) : ");
    scanf("%i%i%i", &thisDay.month, &thisDay.day, &thisDay.year);

    nextDay = dateUpdate(thisDay);

    printf("Tomorrow's date is %i/%i/%.2i.\n", nextDay.month, nextDay.day, nextDay.year % 100);

    return 0;
}


struct date dateUpdate (struct date today)
{
    struct date tomorrow;
    int numberOfDays (struct date d);

    if(today.day != numberOfDays (today))
    {
        tomorrow = (struct date) {today.month, today.day + 1, today.year};
    }
    else if(today.month == 12)
    {
        tomorrow = (struct date) {1, 1, today.year + 1};
    }
    else
    {
        tomorrow = (struct date) {today.month + 1, 1, today.year};
    }

    return tomorrow;
}

int numberOfDays (struct date d)
{
    int days;
    bool isLeapYear (struct date d);
    const int daysPerMonth[12] =
        {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

    if(isLeapYear (d) && d.month == 2)
    {
        days = 29;
    }
    else
    {
        days = daysPerMonth[d.month - 1];
    }

    return days;
}

bool isLeapYear(struct date d)
{
    bool leapYearFlag;

    if ( (d.year % 4 == 0 && d.year % d.year % 100 != 0) || d.year % 400 == 0)
    {
        leapYearFlag = true;
    }
    else
    {
        leapYearFlag = false;
    }

    return leapYearFlag;
}
```

And here is my attempt to utilize pointers in the `updateFunction`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct date
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};


struct date dateUpdate (struct date* today);
int numberOfDays (struct date d);
bool isLeapYear(struct date d);

int main (void)
{
    struct date thisDay, nextDay, *datePtr;

    printf("Enter today's date (mm dd yyyy) : ");
    scanf("%i%i%i", &thisDay.month, &thisDay.day, &thisDay.year);

    datePtr = &thisDay;

    nextDay = dateUpdate(datePtr);

    printf("Tomorrow's date is %i/%i/%.2i.\n", nextDay.month, nextDay.day, nextDay.year % 100);

    return 0;
}


struct date dateUpdate (struct date* today)
{
    struct date tomorrow;
    int numberOfDays (struct date d);

    if(today->day != numberOfDays (*today))
    {
        tomorrow = (struct date) {today->month, today->day + 1, today->year};
    }
    else if(today->month == 12)
    {
        tomorrow = (struct date) {1, 1, today->year + 1};
    }
    else
    {
        tomorrow = (struct date) {today->month + 1, 1, today->year};
    }

    return tomorrow;
}

int numberOfDays (struct date d)
{
    int days;
    bool isLeapYear (struct date d);
    const int daysPerMonth[12] =
        {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

    if(isLeapYear (d) && d.month == 2)
    {
        days = 29;
    }
    else
    {
        days = daysPerMonth[d.month - 1];
    }

    return days;
}

bool isLeapYear(struct date d)
{
    bool leapYearFlag;

    if ( (d.year % 4 == 0 && d.year % d.year % 100 != 0) || d.year % 400 == 0)
    {
        leapYearFlag = true;
    }
    else
    {
        leapYearFlag = false;
    }

    return leapYearFlag;
}
```

Right now both programs compile and seem to run properly.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. But to make a pointer to the struct you would do struct data* tomorrow; And everywhere you have the dot operator just make it into the arrow operator ->. Example: Instead of having tomorrow.day make it tomorrow->day;

Comment: My fault, let me rewrite this car crash of a question.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Omid CompSCI's comment: it is almost just as simple. Almost.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// ALL TESTS OMMITTED!

struct date {
  int month;
  int day;
  int year;
};
// add the pointer mark (asterix)
struct date *dateUpdate(struct date *today);
int numberOfDays(struct date *d);
bool isLeapYear(struct date *d);

int main(void)
{
  // again ,just add the pointer marks
  struct date *thisDay, *nextDay;
  // using a pointer means that all you have is a pointer
  // but you need some memory to store the content
  thisDay = malloc(sizeof(struct date));

  printf("Enter today's date (mm dd yyyy) : ");
  // use the "->" notation to get to the respective storages
  scanf("%i%i%i", &thisDay->month, &thisDay->day, &thisDay->year);

  // dateUpdate() has been changed to accept and return a pointer,
  // so no change in notations here 
  nextDay = dateUpdate(thisDay);
  // again: use the "->" notation to get to the respective storages
  printf("Tomorrow's date is %i/%i/%.2i.\n", nextDay->month, nextDay->day,
     nextDay->year % 100);

  // memory allocated by 'alloc() needs to be free'd, too
  free(nextDay);
  free(thisDay);

  return 0;
}

// just added pointer markings
struct date *dateUpdate(struct date *today)
{
  struct date *tomorrow;
  // again, we need to allocated some memory
  // not only to get storage but also to be able to return it
  tomorrow = malloc(sizeof(struct date));
  // again: use the "->" notation to get to the respective storages
  if (today->day != numberOfDays(today)) {
    // the notation of the cast does not change, the target does
    *tomorrow = (struct date) {
    today->month, today->day + 1, today->year};
  } else if (today->month == 12) {
    *tomorrow = (struct date) {
    1, 1, today->year + 1};
  } else {
    *tomorrow = (struct date) {
    today->month + 1, 1, today->year};
  }
  return tomorrow;
}

int numberOfDays(struct date *d)
{
  int days;
  const int daysPerMonth[12] =
      { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

  if (isLeapYear(d) && d->month == 2) {
    days = 29;
  } else {
    days = daysPerMonth[d->month - 1];
  }

  return days;
}

bool isLeapYear(struct date * d)
{
  bool leapYearFlag;
  // you have one "d.year %" too much in your code
  if ((d->year % 4 == 0 && d->year % 100 != 0) || d->year % 400 == 0) {
    leapYearFlag = true;
  } else {
    leapYearFlag = false;
  }

  return leapYearFlag;
}
```

I hope that makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: Thank you so much!

If declare the non-pointer structures first, along with their size and THEN assign a pointer, I can avoid having to use malloc, right?

Comment: Malloc is not something I've not covered yet and is further along in the book I'm studying.

Comment: If you see my attempt above, I did not use pointer syntax for the other functions such as `isLeapYear` or `numberOfDays`. Are there any benefits to having changed it to pointers? Seeing as the only thing that was changed there was adding a `*` and switching `.` for a `->`

I admit I like your uniformity though :)

Comment: The `malloc` in `dateUpdate()` is necessary because you return the struct. You can leave it there and leave the others unchanged but then you have an unhealthy and error-prone mix. And, well, you wanted it with pointers and that's what I did.

Comment: Okay got it, thank you! 

Two last things, please. Inside the if/else statements of dateUpdate, what is the reason for needing the asterisk with *tomorrow. Because it was already declared and initialized above.

Also, when declaring the function: `struct date *dateUpdate(struct date *today)`

Why is the asterisk next to `dateUpdate` and not next to `struct date*`? It looks confusing to me.

Comment: 1) The asterisk fro `tomorrow` is necessary because you put content into the storage `tomorrow` points to. 2) Whitespace does not matter in declarations. `char * ptr` is the same as `char* ptr` is the same as `char *ptr`

Answer (score 0):

This code can easily be converted to use pointers. Pointers are useful because they provide an alternative to copying the data of your structs each time a function is called. You can still use the normal, pass-by-value mechanics elsewhere. Rewriting the code is very simple and requires few changes. For example, your `struct date dateUpdate();` function can be repurposed to accept pointers by adding the `*` symbol after the type, e.g. `int` to `int *`.
The definition of your function `struct date dateUpdate` would be changed to `struct date *dateUpdate (struct date *today);` meaning that a pointer, or the memory address, of a date struct is being passed. Your code has to be changed in the declaration also. For example, in `bool isLeapYear()`, the line of code
`if ( (d.year % 4 == 0 && d.year % d.year % 100 != 0) || d.year % 400 == 0)`
would have to be changed to 
`if ( (d->year % 4 == 0 && d->year % d->year % 100 != 0) || d->year % 400 == 0)`.
The `->` operator is shorthand for `(*pointer).variable`, as the compiler must be told to get the member of the struct at the **address**, not the actual location of, the pointer. 
Now that the type passed has changed, the calling is different too. Calling `bool isLeapYear()` is now not `bool isLeapYear (d);`, but
`bool isLeapYear (&d);`, as the `&` operator gets the address of the `struct`.
Using this information, here is a converted version of your program: [link.](https://ideone.com/YW52qX)
A big problem however is that much of your code doesn't work, but that is outside the scope of your question.
EDIT: This answer was made before your edit of the question but is still helpful.